# jquery click event returns true but form is not submitted

Tags: jquery, forms, button, onclick

I'm looking for some help in how to troubleshoot this problem.  The following extract is the click handler for the Save button on a form that has a variable layout depending on what type of document is being saved.  Using jquery validation I have set up different rule sets in my own custom objects and it's all been working just fine.

The documents in this application are all associated with a person record and in every other person record I've tried, the document is saved but in one case, the Save button triggers the event, the form validates with no problem and the handler return true.

On stepping thru in Chrome I can see the event object has defaultprevented false.  No errors are put out to the console.  But the postback does not happen.

It's near impossible to expect that anyone will be able to tell me what is actually wrong here but I'm lost as to where to look next.  I have compared the output of the stored procs used to populate the form with each person's ID and can see nothing suspicious coming back from the database.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(idoc.$.SaveButton).off('click').click(function (e) {
        var rv = true;

        $('.idoc-msg-bar').html('').hide();

        // what kind of document are we saving?
        var docType = $(idoc.$.DocTypeDDL).find(':selected').attr('value');
        // get the DocumentType object that knows what to validate
        var dt = idoc.getDocTypeLayout(docType);

        $('form').validate().settings.rules =  dt.ValidatorRules;
        // debug - dump the rules as the validator sees them
        //for (var r in $('form').validate().settings.rules) 
        //    for (var c in $('form').validate().settings.rules[r])
        //        console.log(r + ' --> ' + c + ' --> ' + $('form').validate().settings.rules[r][c]);

        if ($('form').valid()) {
            // get confirmation to overwrite CV if need be
            if ([idoc.DocType.CVVelosiFormat, idoc.DocType.OriginalCV].indexOf(dt.Value) >= 0) {
                $('.idoc-msg-bar').html(idoc.MSG.CVNotes).addClass('required-rel');

                var chk = $(idoc.$.ChkOverwriteCV);
                if (typeof (chk) != 'undefined') {
                    if ($(chk).is(":visible")) {
                        if ($(chk).is(":checked")) {
                            // proceed to server side validation rules
                        } else {
                            $('.idoc-msg-bar').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
                            e.preventDefault();
                            rv = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        $('.idoc-msg-bar').show().effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        rv = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            rv = false;
        }

        return rv;
    });
```

**EDIT:**

Apologies, yes, I meant to include the html too:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabDocs$uctlDocs$btnDocSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabDocs$uctlDocs$btnDocSave&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabDocs_uctlDocs_btnDocSave">
```

**EDIT:**

So copied the person record back into the same table so it would have a different ID and then updated all the related rows with the new id.  And I got the same problem.  So there is definitely something in the data that is messing this up, right?

I'm in the process of reverting the related records back to the original ID and retrying to see which record is causing the problem.  It could still be a column in the person record itself but I'm trying to avoid updating those one by one.

Comment: Is your "save" button also a submit button e.g. `<input type="submit">`? Can you show your HTML too?

Comment: why bother returning anything? your `e.preventDefaults` in all the false places should stop the form being processed

Comment: Which is what i thought.  it's just paranoia that i've added those there cuz i wanted to force return true in case something was interfering with it.

Comment: `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()` appears to be processing your `Save` button click in parallel to you own click handler. Surely you should be hooking into `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` instead?

Comment: You mean call it directly and make my own postback to the server side handler from a non asp.net button?  I guess I could but this works for 4999 out of 5000 records.  Any other ideas?  I've made some progress but I'm gonna update the question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This panel of field was on a tab in a much larger form.  A field on one of the other tabs used a user control that had a property that toggled whether the control had a RequiredFieldValidator.  For some reason this was being triggered.  As my document form wasn't using ASP.NET client-side validation, I just add "CausesValidation=false" to my document form and the problem went away.

So - anybody with weirdness like this - check your other controls for client side validation, your validation groups etc and if you're not using ASP.NET's client side validation, explicitly turn it off on your submit button.  Could save you 3 days and a new bald patch :-)